# Need only the newest Google Form Submitted data to be emailed out based on email address in cell N

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want a simple script that sends the newest google form data submitted to the email address created from the If else statement based on the carrier title in Column J (row 9) Google sheet collecting the data. Unfortunately, I can't share the sheet I am working with because my company doesn't allow us to share outside of the company.

```
    function CustomEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Responses');
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = 700; 
   var dataRange = ss.getRange("A2:Q700"); 
   var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var emailSent = "Email Sent";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
     var carrier = data[i][9];//armored car carrier  
    if (carrier === 'Dunbar/Brinks'){ 
    var  Email = ("xxx@xxx.com");}
    else if (carrier === 'GARDA'){ 
    var  Email = ("xxx@xxx.com");}
    else if (carrier === 'Loomis'){ 
    var  Email = ("xxx@xxx.com");}
    else{ 
    var Email = '';
    }   
  var subject= "New Armored Car Missed Pick-UP";//subject for the email will be// 
    if (Email.length>0);{  
    var row = data[i];      
    var date = row[11];   
    var store = row[2];//Store Name    
    var address = row[3];//Address    
    var city = row[4];//City    
    var state = row[5];//state    
    var manager = row[6];//manager name    
    var reason = row[10];//reason  
    var emailBody = "New Armored Car Pick-Up Report from: " +store+ "\nDate of Missed Pick-Up: " +date+ "\nAddress: " +address+ "\nCity: " +city+ "\nState: " +state+ "\nManager: " +manager+ "\nCarrier: " +carrier+ "\nReason: " +reason;
    var isEmailSent = row[16];
  if (isEmailSent != "Email Sent") {
     MailApp.sendEmail(Email, subject, emailBody); 
    ss.getRange(startRow + i,17).setValue(emailSent);
    };
   };
 }
 }
```

Comment: I think I'll just delete my answer and that might encourage someone else to jump in and help you.

Comment: Is the form adding the data at the bottom of a list of rows? I know you can't show your sheet or code but can you call `getLastRow()` on the Sheet and use the data in that row for populating `row[]` with `e.values`?

Comment: It is adding the data to the last row. I am still new to scripting, so I am unsure of how to to write up the last row script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of reading over the holiday weekend, I rewrote the script and it is now working the way we want. Thank you all for your assistance.

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Responses');
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = 700; 
   var dataRange = ss.getRange("A2:Q700"); 
   var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var emailSent = "Email Sent";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
```

//Body of email in middle///

```
var isEmailSent = row[16];
  if (isEmailSent != "Email Sent") {
     MailApp.sendEmail(Email, subject, emailBody); 
    ss.getRange(startRow + i,17).setValue(emailSent);
    };
   };
 }
 }
```